# What is this called in Android (see picture)?

Tags: android

I would like to know how the green plus sign in the following picture is called:

[image: picture]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I think that "green plus sign" is already a good name for that picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you clarify the question a little bit? Do you want the name of the drawable? It's a probably an ImageButton with a custom circle background.

It's a standard Android drawable - ic_input_add

Here is the whole list of drawables:
http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is an ImageView. Maybe a FrameLayout. Please consider accepting some more answers.